# Avoid Violation of PRIMARY KEY in delete\insert transaction?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, t-sql, concurrency, transactions

I have pretty simple T-SQL query

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE [id] = @Id

INSERT INTO my_table
    ([id], [payload])
VALUES
    (@Id, @Payload)
```

A lot of these queries executing in different threads. INSERT and DELETE are in **transaction** with type **Read Commited**. Everything works good 99.9% of time, but there is an edge case when it fails with:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_my_table'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.my_table'. The duplicate key value is (9).
The statement has been terminated.
```

The problem appears when:

1. We have 2 transactions with the same @Id
2. We don't have a record with @Id in the table my_table

So the 1st and the 2nd transactions start with DELETE. Both transactions delete nothing because there wasn't record in the table my_table. Both start to INSERT and BOOM - Violation of PRIMARY KEY.

The question is how to avoid this case with **Read Commited transaction type** and **without using MERGE statement**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have 2 transactions with the same @Id
> We don't have a record with @Id in the table my_table

This is the scenario that Range Locking is intended to address.  Under SERIALIZABLE or with the HOLDLOCK hint you will take key range locks on empty key ranges.

eg

```
drop table if exists tt
go
create table tt(id int primary key, a int)

begin transaction
    delete from tt 
    where id = 1
    select resource_type, request_mode, request_status
    from sys.dm_tran_locks
    where request_session_id = @@spid 
commit transaction

go

begin transaction
    delete from tt with (holdlock) 
    where id = 1
    select resource_type, request_mode, request_status
    from sys.dm_tran_locks
    where request_session_id = @@spid 
commit transaction
```

outputs

```
(0 rows affected)
resource_type                                                request_mode                                                 request_status
------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
OBJECT                                                       IX                                                           GRANT

(1 row affected)


(0 rows affected)
resource_type                                                request_mode                                                 request_status
------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
KEY                                                          RangeX-X                                                     GRANT
OBJECT                                                       IX                                                           GRANT

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: David, looks like this solution works for me. Do you know how this can affect the performance? Will it slow down the performance dramatically? At the moment I have over 600 transactions per second like these ones.

Comment: It's a key range lock, so as ID is a key it should only block in the case two sessions attempt to insert the same @ID (or perhaps two consecutive ID's).  In any case the impact on throughput should be minimal.